# mongoose.Query.getQuery() returns object ID as a bson type, how do I get it back in plain javscript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;

mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = function () {
  const query = this.getQuery()
  console.log(query) // 
  return exec.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

this.getQuery() returns an object like this

```
{
     _id: ObjectID {
       _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
       id: <Buffer 61 21 9c 61 1b bc 0c 1e c0 30 12 4c>
     },
     collection: 'users'
   }
```

Unfortunately, if I use

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getQuery()))
```

I'm getting the object ID

```
{ _user: '61219c611bbc0c1ec030124c' }
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying prototype is a bad practice and leads to unmaintainable code. I do not suggest you to do so.

As for getting the document as an object, you can use `doc.toObject()`

```
const query = new mongoose.Query();
// your query here
const output = query.exec() // returns doc

const docAsObj = output.toObject() // js object
```

However, in the mongoose docs, it does not  recommend the usage of `mongoose.Query`. Instead, it suggest you to run your query directly on the respective model instead.

More about `mongoose.Query` here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `mongoose` version to a new one helped me. Also there was introduced a new query api function, which returns query as a plain JavaScript object. You can get more info here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-getFilter